# How to persist data in a sorted order in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

This is a newbie question, any help will be appreciated. I have a class `Item` as follows.

```
class Item {
    String name
    // other properties ...

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false, unique: true)
        // other constraints ...
    }
}
```

How do I persist the `Item`s in a sorted order in Grails/GORM? Meaning, if I did

```
new Item(name: 'a').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
new Item(name: 'c').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
new Item(name: 'b').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

println Item.getAll().name
```

I should get `[a, b, c]`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your domain class

```
static mapping = {
    sort name: "desc" //"asc"
}
```

Comment: This works fine, thank you! One comment though, I have to use Item.list(), instead of Item.getAll(). The getAll() method does not seem to print the sorted list even with the mapping included. I like this mapping approach, since I do not have to sort() every time I retrieve the data.

Comment: sort name: "desc" does not guarantee an insertion order. It's a way to customize the default property to sort by for query results (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/sort.html)

Comment: @cantoni: Is there any way to guarantee insertion order? I think I get your point - thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Presisting doesn't matter but ,what matters the way you retrieve it and you can simply do as   follow

```
println Item.list().sort() 

println Item.list().sort(){ //write your groovy clouser here to sort asc and dec }
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I was wondering if there was any way to persist the data in a sorted order in the first place? The reason is that if it is a big table with many rows and if I retrieve the data very frequently, sort() will be slower I think (as every time I retrieve the data it will be doing the sorting). The background is, the Item is a glossary of items, and I will be adding new items to the table less frequently, but will be retrieving the data very frequently. Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: To persist items in a specific order, you can map your collection as a List. See http://docs.codehaus.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/228171330 for details.

Comment: Thank you, @rcgeorge23. I could use the SortedSet for custom ordering. I found the latest version of the doc you have referenced (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps). Thanks for the very helpful tips!